# Microsoft Graph API: How to access guest calendar events using API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am working on the integration of the outlook calendar with our app. I am trying to get the calendar events of the guest user. So far I have done the following steps.

Registered an app in the Azure Active Directory admin centre and added the following API permissions.

[API permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB2Uu.png)

Then I used the following API call to get the access token.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

I used this token to get the user list which is working fine.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

Then I am using user_id from this result to call the following APIs

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars/events
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/events
```

I am getting a successful result for Member users but getting the following error for guest users

```
>AuthOMMissingRequiredPermissions
>The AadGuestPft token doesn't contain the permissions required by the target API.
```

Any Idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To get guest users(external) you can use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest' Graph API endpoint. This will give you all external users details in response. Event API will only work for the user within tenant, for external users who does not have license it will not work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Vicky, but as I mentioned above, I am getting users, which is not a problem. the only concern is how our clients will see their events as they will be not in the tenant in the first place. Is there any way I can ask the user to follow some API or link to add himself in a tenant ??

Comment: yeah , you can follow the doc to add external user in the tenant - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal.

Comment: @vickykumar I have build a SaaS application where I want user to login into my application and they can see their calendar events and add new events as well. 
I have registered some guest users which are not part of my organization now they are able to login but event API is giving me this error 
{\"error\":{\"code\":\"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI\",\"message\":\"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.\"}}

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @vickykumar I have build a SaaS application where I want user to login into my application and they can see their calendar events and add new events as well. 
I have registered some guest users which are not part of my organization now they are able to login but event API is giving me this error 
{\"error\":{\"code\":\"MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI\",\"message\":\"The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.\"}}

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, please find the similar issue - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/930733/graph-api-send-mail-error-mailboxnotenabledforrest, hope this help to fix your issue, thanks